# Unable to execute any query in drupal 7 for oracle database connectivity

Tags: oracle, drupal, oracle11g, drupal-7, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to install drupal on Oracle 11g database. I have successfully connected to Oracle DB and the option is showing in Drupal Installation page.
Post logging into DB using the details given in the installation page, the process is failing throwing *OCIStatement* exceptions. I tried to change queries to simple one like

> select * from dual

but it is failing with the following exception: 
**ORA-24338: Statement handle not executed**. Since this is in Drupal, we cannot change any queries already written. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks for your support!

Comment: Does a pure PHP OCI8 test program work?

Comment: Php oci8 programs are working fine. I'm able to execute queries directly. But this issue is seen only when trying to run the query in drupal

Comment: Knowing your OS would help.   What Oracle software do you have installed - is there a clash?

Comment: I'm running on Windows 10. I've installed oracle 11g database, a few other oracle softwares are also installed, so will that cause a problem?

Comment: You just need to make sure that the PATH that is set when Drupal runs contains only one Oracle library directory.